# How can I do batch predictions on Google AI Platform Unified using a XGBoost model?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, xgboost, google-ai-platform

How can I use XGBoost on Google AI Platform Unified for batch predictions?

I can perform Online predictions with no problem, but when I submit a batch job request, it returns an error ("Could not predict, DMatrix initialization error).

I'm submiting a csv file with the same column names as the ones used for training. I try doing it with the dataframe formatted as jsonl file and have no result. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I could do it using the format jsonl, putting each list line as a list with the ordered features. Noneless, I cannot give any keys to the datapoint - which makes the predictions a bit useless.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/getting-started-scikit-xgboost#create_a_model_version) f you plan to use the model version for batch prediction, then you must use runtime version 2.1 or earlier. Additionally, please include the commands used  when submitting a batch prediction job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out: you can't. Perform batch predictions using Apache Beam running on Dataflow instead. Runs like a charm.